# combine tables (9M records) and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have 10 tables with 0.5+M records of persons each (in total 9M records). Structure is very similar in each table. Now I want to remove duplicates within each table and across tables, or say I want to see who is present in all the tables and how many unique records I actually have. **But the problem is the huge amount of data.**

So I planned to create different tables - 1 for email address, 1 for mobile no., 1 for address and so on. But now if each table have 5M records then my tables get very slow.

1 solution is that I create tables as per month of date-of-birth, will lead to 12 tables and then I will be able to sort data within each table.

Please suggest what should I do? Data is 9.6M records / 3.2GB

Also suggest how to move data from 1 table to other quickly.

Comment: What is the current schema you're working on?

Comment: No schema as such, all tables are independent records of different times. Each record has Name, email, mobile, dob, and so on.. But a person may change his email, mobile no; and name may be typed a little differently in some situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table with identical structure but with [unique constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) on the set of columns that determine uniqueness of a row.

Then use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`....`SELECT FROM` to transfer all the rows from old table to the new table. The syntax can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).

Then truncate the old tables and use `INSERT INTO`....`SELECT FROM` to transfer rows back to the original table.

You might want to add unique constraint to your original tables to prevent duplicates from being created in the first place.

Comment: Sounds good, will try this. I don't require to change old tables as such.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a db design problem. Even a 3.2gb dataset can be made to run quickly enough... Optimizing the database structure and using appropriate indexing, caching etc will be much better than splitting down into yet more tables. You want to be running as few a queries as possible, and as simple a query as possible.

If you do break them down yet more, you'll be shooting yourself in the foot in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a specific [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that combine the result from the 12 tables, and then query on the view to get the desired filtered result ...

Comment: Second this! Lots and lots of IF conditionals to make it exactly what you need!

Comment: @LoganBibby what are these IF conditionals?

Comment: Well, it would fully depend on your schema as to what the IF conditionals would be. But for each field you have, you'd have to pull data from each of the tables. To do that, you'd need to use IF conditionals if there's any sort of difference in any of the schemes.